# Dominating Positive Part James-Stein

Tags: estimators, steins-phenomenon

Is dominating Positive Part James Stein estimator when estimating the mean of a multivariate normal of dimension 3 with known variance(all equal) an open problem?

If not, what is this estimator called? Can you point out some references?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a published reply to this challenge, by Peter Yi-Shi Shao and William E. Strawderman in 1994: https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1176325640

[image]

They provide conditions on estimators of the type

[image]

to ensure domination. Interestingly such estimators are *also* inadmissible and hence are dominated by other (generalised Bayes) estimators (see p. 1530).

Comment: Do we know the admissible Generalized Bayes estimators that dominate JS, or do we just rely on some existence theorem?

Comment: No, as mentioned on p.1530, there exist generalised Bayes estimators dominating this one, they may belong to the class discussed on p. 1530, if not to (3.1) [which does not contain analytic functions], but no explicit improvement is known.